# Global variables in CGO block - memory leak and thread safety in GO

Tags: c, pointers, go, cgo

I'm trying to figure out if there is a thread safety and/or memory leak issue associated with global variables declared in a CGO block.  Here's some pseudo code:

```
/*    
char* globalchar;
int globalnum;

void init() {
 globalchar = "do something";
}

int process() {
  if (globalchar==NULL) {
    init();
  }
  globalnum=0;
  while (condition test) {
    dosomething_that_takes_time();
    globalnum++
  }
  return globalnum;
}
*/
import "C"
func goproc() {
  val := int(C.process())
}
```

goproc() gets called across multiple threads.

Question 1. Is globalnum thread safe?  Can it get manipulated by different threads at the same time?

Question 2. Is there any possible problems associated with doing the init() in this pattern to only run once?  When a singleton pattern is used in Java, we "synchronize" the init() method to make sure only one person can run it at the same time.

Question 3. Will globalnum and globalchar automatically get garbage collected?  I notice a lot of: defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(somecpointer)).  Does this need to be done with global variables declared in the CGO block?

Any advice would be helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re question 1: no, this is not safe.  Use a mutex somewhere—in the C code itself, most likely, with a POSIX style mutex—to synchronize access to shared data.  Or, if you prefer, use a C11 atomic integer.

Re question 2: this too is not safe.  Use a mutex somewhere.

Re question 3: the global C variables do not need GC.  One is not a pointer, and the other is a pointer that points to static-duration C memory holding the C string literal `do something` (after `init` anyway).

Comment: Thanks!  Makes sense.  Definitely needed to course correct after reading your answer.